# I lied about my father being abusive when I was younger. How can I repent?

Tags: sin, parents, lying

Salaam. When I was in high school I used to cut myself for dumb reasons (sympathy? attention?) and I would tell friends that my father was the one who had done it and they thought he was abusive. It's been close to 10 years since then, and I'm extremely ashamed of what I did as my father is a great man. Islamically, what do I have to do to be able to right this wrong other than making dua? Is it required for me to find/reach out to people in high school to tell them I had been lying about my father? Is this something I need to tell my father I did awhile back?

May Allah forgive me

Answer (score 0):

I lied about my father's abuse when I was young. How can I repent?
There is a lie about repentance: The Holy Quran and Islamic traditions are well used that if a person truly repents and observes the conditions of repentance, his repentance will be accepted without hesitation and God Almighty will forgive his sins. The role of repentance in opening up to happiness and being on the path of truth and correcting past wrongdoings and opening the door of hope to man is very fundamental. It often happens that a person slips during his life and especially at the beginning of training and self-improvement; If the doors of return are closed to him, he will be disappointed and will be lost forever. Therefore, in the Islamic school of education, repentance is a very important educational principle, and Islam invites all sinners to reform themselves and make amends. Enter. The truth of repentance is the remorse and repentance of sin that requires the decision to leave sin in the future, and if the past sin is something that can be compensated, it must seek redress, and thus the pillars of repentance can be summarized in four things: Repentance, 2. Deciding to leave in the future, 3. Compensation for the past, 4. Asking for forgiveness from God.

Repentance, then, is not just asking for forgiveness or remorse for the past and even deciding to leave in the future, but in addition to all this, the sinner must be compensated and compensate for the corruption he has committed. It is not right, for example, to accuse someone of lying and trickery in front of others and then ask for forgiveness in a private home. Therefore, he must compensate and prepare the rights of God such as prayer, fasting, worship and duties that he has lost and abandoned, as well as the rights of the people that he has ruined, and return the rights of the people to them and, if possible, access them. Seek satisfaction and solubility.

Ref: https://www.porseman.com/article/%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%A8%D9%87-%D8%A7%D8%B2-%D8%AF%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%BA--%D8%AC%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86-%D8%AF%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%BA/12401